# Issues with persistent volume on DigitalOcean Kubernetes cluster

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, digital-ocean

Just created a managed 2-node Kubernetes (ver. 1.22.8) cluster on DigitalOcean (DO).
After installing WordPress using Bitnami Helm chart, and then installing a WP plugin, the site became unreachable.
Looking into DO K8s dashboard in the deployment section, the `wordpress` deployment shows the following error:

```
0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.

AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "pvc-c859847e-f250-4e71-9ed3-63c92cc01f50" : rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded

MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-c859847e-f250-4e71-9ed3-63c92cc01f50" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = formatting disk failed: exit status 1 cmd: 'mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0DO_Volume_pvc-c859847e-f250-4e71-9ed3-63c92cc01f50' output: "mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)\nThe file /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0DO_Volume_pvc-c859847e-f250-4e71-9ed3-63c92cc01f50 does not exist and no size was specified.\n"

Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404
```

As I'm quite new to K8s, I don't know much how to troubleshoot this.
Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I was able to reproduce the error and found what triggers it.
WordPress Bitnami charts installs several WP plugins by default. As soon as I try to delete them, the error shows up and the persistent volume gets corrupted...
Is this maybe a bug or it's standard behavior?